# Intermittently merging up release branch into master using GitHub PRs

Tags: git, github

In a project I am working on, we have a `master` branch which is our development branch. We create a `release` branch from this when we are finalizing our build for release. We have just moved to GitHub and are using PRs. We also automatically delete branches after a merge. Additionally, we have branch protection on, so the only way to merge into protected branches is via PR.

Our `release` branch is typically active for 2 weeks. During this time, we would like to merge `release` into `master` every couple of 1-2 days to keep it up to date with our changes in `release`. In a world without PRs and branch protection I could do something like (assume the merge is uneventful) the following.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git merge origin/release/X.Y.Z
git push
```

And of course I would build and test post merge and before pushing.

With our current process, I cannot create a PR where the base branch is `master` and the compare branch is `release/X.Y.Z`, because after the merge, `release/X.Y.Z` would be deleted. Additionally even if I could, doing this to merge wouldn't have my pass of building and testing locally on my machine (CI pass would run, but obviously I should be doing it as well locally).

Is the typical way to do this with a temp branch? For example

```
git checkout -b temp --no-track master
git merge origin/release/X.Y.Z
git push --set-upstream origin temp
```

And then creating the PR using base as `master` and compare as `temp`.

Thanks.

Comment: The merge-and-delete policy seems a bit harsh. It's not under your control to make it optional?

Comment: it is done this way right now because the team is an outsourced team working with some of our team members. But all are very new to git and the dev skill set varies greatly across team members.